# How to pass a list of paths to spark.read.textFile?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Currently we can successfully load multiple log files (text) into a Spark (v 2.1) dataframe and map each line to the linked file path using glob syntax, eg.

```
    val df = spark.read.textFile(
      "wasb://container_name@storage_name/base_dir/2018/*.txt"    
    ).withColumn("input_file_name", input_file_name) // Add column with filename for grouping.
```

We would now like to pass to "spark.read.textFile" a list of paths prepared beforehand, "blob_paths", i.e. have the snippet rewritten as

```
    val df = spark.read.textFile(
      blob_paths    
    ).withColumn("input_file_name", input_file_name) // Add column with filename for grouping.
```

But we cannot make this work. The paths are okay but the list seems to break "spark.read.textFile" in the following

```
    <console>:31: error: overloaded method value textFile with alternatives:
      (paths: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] <and>
      (path: String)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String]
     cannot be applied to (List[String])
           val df = spark.read.textFile(
                        ^
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Try passing `blob paths :_*`

Comment: omg. it works! Thanks so much.

Comment: Feel free to accept answer by bluephantom below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar example, that should help:

```
val paths = Seq(
   "/FileStore/tables/ALT2018_01.txt",
   "/FileStore/tables/ALT2018_02.txt")

val df2 = 
   spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("sep", ",")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("header", "false")
  .load(paths: _*) 

df2.show
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer from cricket 007 works (note ":_*")

```
    val df2 = spark.read.textFile(
        blob_paths:_*
    ).withColumn("input_file_name", input_file_name) // Add column with filename for grouping.
```

thanks a lot

Also the answer from thebluephantom works :)

Answer (score -2):

The method "spark.read.textFile" doesn't support a List, you can try use this method

```
spark.read.textFile("patha", "pathb")
```

It will work. I hope this will helps you.

Comment: It supports variable arguments, so you can convert a list to that